# Undefined function with bcrypt-nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

I'm using bcrypt-nodejs to hashify passwords within a pre save function.
I can't figure out why I continue to receive the error '[TypeError: undefined is not a function]' inside the callback function of bcrypt.hash.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    validate = require('mongoose-validate'),
    bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10,
    REQUIRED_PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8;

function validateStringLength (value) {
    return value && value.length >= REQUIRED_PASSWORD_LENGTH;
}

var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
            validate: [validate.email, 'is not a valid email address']
    },
    passHash: {type: String,
                required: true,
                validate: [validateStringLength, 'The password must be of min ' + REQUIRED_PASSWORD_LENGTH + ' characters length.']}
});

schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var self = this;

    if (!self.isModified('passHash')) return next();

    bcrypt.hash(self.passHash, SALT_WORK_FACTOR, null, function encryptedPassword (err, hash) {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        self.passHash = hash;
        next();
    });
});

schema.set('autoIndex', App.env !== 'production');

var Model = mongoose.model('User', schema);
module.exports = Model;
```

I checked the parameters passed and they are correct.
Also the hash returned is null.

Does anyone had a similar experience?
I'm using bcrypt-nodejs because bcrypt gives me error during the installation with npm.

Comment: use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-inzi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reproducable with this:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')

bcrypt.hash('foo', 10, null, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

The issue is that the salt needs to be a string (internally, `bcrypt-nodejs` is using `salt.charAt()`, and `charAt()` is undefined for numbers).

You probably want this:

```
 bcrypt.hash(self.passHash, bcrypt.genSaltSync(SALT_WORK_FACTOR), ...);
```

(or the async version, `bcrypt.genSalt()`)

Comment: I didn't notice this different parameter from bcrypt (the error is with bcrypt-nodejs), thanks